# Can we determine if a reference frame is inertial or non-inertial by looking at an accelerating object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames, machs-principle

if we find that in a given frame, an object being acted upon by a force and is accelerating with respect to the frame would that mean that the reference frame in which this object exist is inertial or non-inertial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of Newton's First law as a *definition* of an inertial frame

> An inertial frame is one in which an object that experiences no net force moves with a constant velocity vector.

together with a statement that Newton's other laws only apply in inertial frames.

So, before analyzing a system using Newton II, one should do an "inertial frame test": consider an object with zero net force on it, e.g., a ball sitting on the ground (normal up, gravity down, net zero); if that ball does not accelerate, then you are in an inertial frame.  If you were in the back of an accelerating truck and performed the same experiement, you would see the ball mysteriously move from rest.  This "ghost force" indicates that you are not in an inertial frame.

So, to answer your question: just observing the acceleration of an object alone does not tell you a frame is inertial or non-inertial. But if an object appears to accelerate and there are no evident forces to explain that acceleration, then the frame is non-inertial.